# Proving $\oint (\vec{K} \cdot \vec{r})d\vec{l}=-\vec{K} \times\int d \vec{a}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, curl

I have to show that,
$$\oint (\vec{K} \cdot \vec{r})d\vec{l}=-\vec{K} \times\int d \vec{a}$$

Here, $\vec{K}$ is constant vector and $\vec{r}$ is position vector.

I have approached by applying Stokes' Theorem,

$$\oint (\vec{K} \cdot \vec{r})d\vec{l}=\int \nabla \times (\vec{K} \cdot \vec{r})  d \vec{a}$$

At this point, I'm stuck and unable to draw any further results.

Comment: You can't use Stokes or Greens because this is a scalar loop integral --> you are currently taking the curl of a scalar product. Try parameterizing the curve you are given and see what that might yield

Comment: How can I do that?